Private Repo to Org Fork doesn't work with Github APPs?
I'm currently facing an issue with GitHub Apps when forking repositories between organizations and individual accounts. Specifically, it seems like the "private repo A to Org B Fork" functionality isn't working as expected when using GitHub Apps.
I'm hoping someone here might have experience with this or can provide some guidance.
We have a GitHub App installed in target organization, installed on client account with access to "repo A", and we're trying to fork a repository from one client to target. However, the process fails with the message "Resource not accessible by integration". Note that if the client grants permissions for all the repositories, the flow works and the fork is created.
The app has the following permissions:

Read access to code and metadata
Read and write access to administration, checks, commit statuses, issues, and pull requests

Here's what we've tried:
Forking a private repository (repo A) from User A to Org B using the GitHub App's installation token.
Ensuring that the GitHub App has the correct permissions for both organizations and clients
Verifying that the GitHub App's installation is active
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Verified permissions for the GitHub App.
Checked logs for any error messages or failures.
Tried with both public and private repositories. (works on public ones and if the user grants permissions for all repositories)
I’ve also searched through GitHub's documentation and the GitHub Community but haven’t found any clear answers related to this specific issue.
Thanks
